# Where can I find graphs the values of alternative crypto currencies?

Tags: alternatives, charts

Hashrates and value in BTC. Is there one site that can show them all, perhaps even on the same chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at http://www.ltc-charts.com you can see long term charts for litecoin

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget http://www.cryptocoincharts.info/ which has charts for LTC, PPC, DVC, NMC, IXC, LQC, and SC in a nice clean interface.

Answer (score 0):

Today, if you've found this question, you'll probably know that [CoinMarketCap](https://coinmarketcap.com/) and [CoinCap.io](https://coincap.io/) are popular sites for tracking the BTC or USD value of cryptocurrencies. But there are way too many altcoins to display them on the same chart.